# Python - OpenCV and Excel

Tags: python, excel, opencv, pdf

i've got over 400 images to analyze and do some spreadsheets with data which are contained on these images.

I'm attaching a simplified [example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1gxk.jpg)

I've got a template images of all types of objects and "turns" also i've got excel spreadsheet template.
Here's the goal: i've got to create excel spreadsheets (one for every single image) containing distance of object (that weird 0+000 stuff), name of an object and/or type of the road but i'm a very beginner of programming and i've never used OpenCV technology so i'm asking for some advice.

Everything in a spreadsheet should be sorted by a distance.

If anything is unclear i'm sorry and please tell what should I describe more exactly.

Comment: So, you're trying to extract the text from these images?  It would be WAY smarter to save this information in its original form when those images are created.

Comment: actually everything is in PDF files and distance is a text but other data are expressed by a graphical symbol so I thought about getting distance from PDF and then convert files into image form

Comment: Not sure I fully understand: If your target is to extract text information from pdfs, you may want to try the “built-in” capability of Excel whether it can provide you with the desired data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/pdf

Comment: Also not clear what is your expectation regarding openCV: basically it is just a library, you can use e.g. in Python, that helps you with various picture manipulation and detection etc. bottom line is that you still need to produce the Python code for your use case. As one small example you may want to check: whether openCV support loading pictures from within an Excel file.

Comment: @Edward re: openVC I encourage you to start with some of the plenty tutorials and/or YouTube videos, so you get a basic understanding first (assuming you have some basic Python experience).  Good luck!

Comment: if you have PDFs, you need to read the PDFs, not convert to image. -- there are libraries to mess with excel files. openpyxl. and for tabular stuff: pandas. -- you really can't approach this without having the necessary background/education. this task is comparably huge. you'd need to know a ton of techniques. can't just google that because you don't have the knowledge to even ask the right questions. -- a mere *sketch* of the data is also not terribly useful. we need to see the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Over the past 10 hours you could have perhaps done 40 imports manualy per hour and the 400 item task would be just cleanup.

However to explain why its achievable, but also highly likely with mistakes, using automation here is your image after OCR and convert to PDF. Thus it could be output in a csv table for import to excel. (Issues described under image)

[image]

OCR has several natural failings so you may note an entry is missing `0+860` also two numeric entries are not as expected, this is because OCR is one character at a time then compared with a dictionary to self correct words but cannot correct random numbering.

You could do better using a Service, but still need to resolve what format of output you are after. And as you see here the layout is not useful. `bitumen road` and `dirt road` should both be lower down, by one cell.
[image]

The next problem is how to transform the columns and rows into your desired excel order without any scaling ?

In summary for 400 similar I would have templated workflow as much as possible and set one day pay as my target cost, possibly paying somebody else if needed.